# Hide Div onclick outside

Tags: javascript, html, hide

On my website I have a div that pops up when the user clicks a form. I am using the onclick event handler for the div to appear. I want the div to hide itself when the user clicks anywhere other than on the div. I cant use onblur...because it doesnt work for divs. Can someone suggest an alternative?

Thank you.

Here is what my code looks like:
Javascript:

```
function hideDiv() {
    if (document.getElementById) { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6 
        document.getElementById('mydiv').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    else {
        if (document.layers) { // Netscape 4 
            document.mydiv.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
        else { // IE 4 
            document.all.mydiv.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }
}

function showDiv() {
    if (document.getElementById) { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6 
        document.getElementById('mydiv').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    else {
        if (document.layers) { // Netscape 4 
            document.mydiv.visibility = 'visible';
        }
        else { // IE 4 
            document.all.mydiv.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just found an easy solution using onmouseover / out event handler.

hideDiv() function is called only if variable `mouse_out` is true.

```
var mouse_out;
mydiv.onmouseover = function(){ mouse_out = false }; // mouse is over div
mydiv.onmouseout = function(){ mouse_out = true }; // mouse outside
document.onclick = function(){
   if(mouse_out)
      hideDiv(),   // hides mydiv
      document.onclick = null; // disables next clicks on document
};
```

It works on every browser I tested, also IE 5.
(IE4 and NS4 I don't know)

Comment: By far the best method I've seen.  Most require juggling dynamic events as they happen -- this tracks the state of the div and takes action based on that state, not some other action.  I use a slight variant; I track the state of the div by adding and removing a class instead of a variable.   This makes it easier to track status on multiple divs and more easily handle complex logic that changes the state.  But the core pattern is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The way I handled those kind of things in the past is create a transparent layer behind the div (use a BG image that is completely transparent) which has CSS somewhere along the lines of:

```
div#overlay{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image:url('transparent.gif');
  z-index: 1;
}
```

This div is of course only "visible" when the Div on top is visible.
and then attach an onclick event handler to hide again.

Make sure your "pop-up div" has a z-index of at least 2.

Comment: I am not sure, but wouldn't be `background:transparent;` enough (instead using transparent image)? I haven't tested that of course, I am just curious.

Comment: Probably, but I think a transparent image would be more stable, just to maintain cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Can you paste the code for the onclick event handler? I am experimenting with the code below. But the div closes when I click on it.
function monitorClick(e){var evt = (e)?e:event;
var theElem=(evt.srcElement)?evt.srcElement:evt.target;
if(theElem.className == "form"){if(document.getElementById('mydiv').style.visibility = 'hidden')
{document.getElementById('mydiv').style.visibility ='visible';} else{document.getElementById('mydiv').style.visibility = 'hidden';}}else if(theElem.id != "mydiv"){document.getElementById('mydiv').style.visibility = 'hidden';}}
document.onclick = monitorClick;